# when I excute pyinstaller > error happens

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller, exe

when I command `pyinstaller` to make exe file like this

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary "chromedriver.exe";"." tweet.py
```

then error happens.

```
PS C:\selenium> pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary "chromedriver.exe";"." tweet.py
위치 줄:1 문자:59
+ pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary "chromedriver.exe";"." tweet.py
+                                                           ~~~~~~~~
식 또는 문에서 예기치 않은 'tweet.py' 토큰입니다.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should solve it

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary "chromedriver.exe;." tweet.py
```

`;` was being treated as a token by the parser and so it raised an error `UnexpectedToken`, you have to include it within the same string.

Comment: within same string means? where I have to write ?

Comment: It means that you need to change `"chromedriver.exe";"."` to `"chromedriver.exe;."` in the command.

Comment: Thank you very much. original error resolved!! however, "chromedriver.exe;." then another error happen,, I can't findout exe file. also, during making exe file, following warning show so many file missing module named then no exe file exist

Comment: and last description show 'TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)'

Comment: @AngdreLee The exe file will be in the `dist` folder if the build was successful. The error you are pointing out could be from your script. I will need more information to be able to tell the issue, I suggest you to ask a new question and include all the details.